# Transfer video file from OS X Lion to iPod touch 4th gen with iOS 5

Tags: software-recommendation, ipod-touch, ios

I have a recently purchased MacBook Pro with Lion and I want to transfer a video file to my iPod touch. The only problem is this is not the Mac with which my iPod touch library is synced, so I cannot really use iTunes sync feature. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Air Sharing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sharing/id289943355?mt=8) will provide a network drive the Mac can drop files onto so you can view them on your touch.

Comment: will it use network traffic. I mean outside my LAN.

Comment: As long as both the MacBook and the iDevice are in the same LAN/WLAN they should be able to connect just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a workaround here, you might be able to use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com). Store the file in your Dropbox account on your Mac, download the iOS client, and star the file as a favorite on your iPod touch. I believe that will cache it on the iPod touch. Then, when you click it, it should play.

You will need a wireless internet connection for the Touch on the first sync, but once it's starred as a favorite, it should be accessible even when offline.

Comment: I am aware of this workaround but I was more specifically looking for a non-internet thing, the one I can do without internet connection.